# what is meant by Defaults:visiblepw in /etc/sudoers file

Tags: sudo

When i was reading sudo config file, there is a line `Defaults visiblepw` . i read the definition for the visiblepw in manual page

```
visiblepw         By default, sudo will refuse to run if the user must
                       enter a password but it is not possible to disable echo
                       on the terminal.  If the visiblepw flag is set, sudo
                       will prompt for a password even when it would be visi-
                       ble on the screen.  This makes it possible to run
                       things like “ssh somehost sudo ls since by default,
                       ssh(1) does not allocate a tty when running a command.
                       This flag is off by default.
```

it is difficult to understand, Can anyone explain the visiblepw in sudoers file.

Comment: Exactly what it says. It tries to make the password you input invisible to anyone looking over your shoulder but if it can't do that, it won't consider it a show stopper.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you know that if you call sudo and it asks for your password you can't see it when typing. sudo does this by disabling echo, which means that it disables the shells functionality to write on the screen until you finished writing your password.

Now there are certain situations in which sudo can't disable echo, one example is given in the manpage. By default sudo throws an error if thats the case and doesn't allow you to enter your password, since someone could be looking over your shoulder. With visiblepw you can disable this behaviour, although I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Bratchley, @Metalfreak Sorry for late reply . i was trying to know the difference with defaults visible and without visible .still it is not clear for my me . i give a example . i have a user `test` im adding the following lines r in sudoers file   `Defaults:test !visiblepw` and `test ALL=(ALL) ALL`.what will be the expected output while running sudo command

Comment: It won't have any direct effect and will behave as normal in most situations. You notice visiblepw when for some reason or another sudo has to show the password you are typing. Normally it aborts under these circumstances to protect your privacy, but when visiblepw is set it continues.

Comment: Re: "which means that it disables the shells functionality to write on the screen": it's not the shell that's responsible for doing that (no shells need be involved, in fact), it's the tty.